# Is this validation rule written as the logic I'm trying to follow?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, validation-rule

```
AND(
    Ready_for_Booking__c,
    OR(
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Purchasing")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Changed Order")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Renewal")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Archived")),
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won - Prior to fusion"))
    )
)
```

Hi, I've been stuck on this for a few hours and I don't know where the error is, basically, what I'm trying to do is, Ready_for_Booking__c, cannot be checked (is a checkbox) until the opportunity is on Purchasing Stage; however if I only include Purchasing on the validation rule, then I won't be able to change the stage to any of the Closed stages, that's why I include them; the issue I'm facing, is that when I try to save an opportunity on Purchasing or any Closed stage, the Error Message appears.

Thanks in advance, I'll try to test another ways to solve this if I found any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `NOT(OR(...))` instead of `OR(NOT(...),NOT(...),...)`. The pattern you have will always return true if any value if any value matches, since if the value matches "Purchasing", for example, it will not equal "Closed Won". `OR(X, Y)` returns true if `X` or `Y` is true, so it will always be true.

We can trivially prove this with [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which state that:

> NOT(A) AND NOT(B) == NOT(A OR B)

and

> NOT(A) OR NOT(B) == NOT(A AND B)

It is this latter rule that shows that `NOT(A) OR NOT(B)` will result in `NOT(A AND B)`, and the stage field cannot simultaneously be equal to "Purchasing" and "Closed Won" at the same time, so the formula will always return true, which triggers the validation.

Here's a revised version:

```
AND(
    Ready_for_Booking__c,
    NOT(
       OR(
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Purchasing"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Changed Order"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Renewal"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Archived"),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won - Prior to fusion")
        )
    )
)
```

However, this is unnecessarily wasteful, so we can use the CASE function to tidy things up:

```
AND(
    Ready_for_Booking__c,
    0 = CASE(
        StageName, "Purchasing", 1,
        "Closed Won", 1,
        "Closed Changed Order", 1,
        "Closed Renewal", 1,
        "Closed Lost", 1,
        "Closed Archived", 1,
        "Closed Won - Prior to fusion", 1,
        0
    )
)
```